# Python: Concatenate 3 lists into csv file?

Tags: python

I have three lists:

`name = ['rob', 'mike', 'bob']
age = ['19, '32', '88']
id = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']`

Is there a way to concatenate these vertically and get a CSV as below?

`rob, 19, aaa
mike, 32, bbb
bob, 88, ccc`

Comment: You should be able to write an indexed loop and then just create the final string inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and `zip` to do this.

```
name = ['rob', 'mike', 'bob']
age = ['19', '32', '88']
id = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    data = list(zip(name, age, id))
    for row in data:
        row = list(row)
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
print("Program completed")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'age':age,'id':id}).to_csv('your.csv')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,j,k in zip(name, age, id):
    print ('{}, {}, {}'.format(i,j,k))
```

Output:

```
rob, 19, aaa
mike, 32, bbb
bob, 88, ccc
```